# igraph in R: Directed graphs (with arrows) causes vertex color transparency

Tags: r, igraph, transparency, directed-graph, vertices

I am using the package `igraph` in `R` to be able to plot a network. However, when passing the `directed = TRUE` flag within the `graph_from_data_frame` command, it appears exactly how it should in R Studio's plot pane. However, once I preview as a PDF (Export, Save as PDF, Preview) OR Save Plot as PDF, all vertices of the graph are transparent. However, setting the `directed = FALSE` flag, the colors are as expected.

**Setting up the data**

```
stack.vtx <- data.frame(Dept = c("C-IIAC",  "EES-16",   "EES-17",   "A-1",  "ISR-1",    "ISR-2",    "ISR-6",    "NEN-5",    "AOT-AE",   "MPA-CINT", "MPA-MAGLAB",   "MPA-Q",    "MST-8",    "P-1",  "P-4",  "SIGMA-1",  "CCS-2",    "CCS-3",    "CCS-6",    "T-1",  "T-2",  "T-3",  "T-4",  "T-5",  "E-6",  "J-4",  "J-6",  "M-3",  "M-6",  "Q-5",  "AMPP-4",   "PT-DO",    "XCP-3",    "XCP-4",    "XCP-8",    "XTD-PRI"), 
                        Count = c(2,    2,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  1,  1,  2,  1,  2,  3,  4,  1,  1,  2,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  2), 
                        Cols = c("#8B4513", "#8B4513",  "#8B4513",  "#FFB90F",  "#FFB90F",  "#FFB90F",  "#FFB90F",  "#FFB90F",  "#CDC8B1",  "#CDC8B1",  "#CDC8B1",  "#CDC8B1",  "#CDC8B1",  "#CDC8B1",  "#CDC8B1",  "#CDC8B1",  "#FF6347",  "#FF6347",  "#FF6347",  "#FF6347",  "#FF6347",  "#FF6347",  "#FF6347",  "#FF6347",  "#9AC0CD",  "#9AC0CD",  "#9AC0CD",  "#9AC0CD",  "#9AC0CD",  "#9AC0CD",  "#00CDCD",  "#00CDCD",  "#8A2BE2",  "#8A2BE2",  "#8A2BE2",  "#8A2BE2"))



stack.edges <- data.frame(from = c("AOT-AE",    "AOT-AE",   "C-IIAC",   "C-IIAC",   "CCS-2",    "EES-16",   "EES-16",   "EES-16",   "ISR-1",    "ISR-1",    "ISR-2",    "ISR-2",    "J-4",  "J-4",  "MPA-CINT", "MPA-CINT", "MPA-Q",    "MPA-Q",    "NEN-5",    "NEN-5",    "P-1",  "Q-5",  "T-1",  "T-1",  "T-2",  "T-2",  "T-2",  "T-2",  "XCP-4",    "XTD-PRI",  "XTD-PRI",  "XTD-PRI",  "XTD-PRI"), 
                          to = c("CCS-3",   "J-6",  "AMPP-4",   "PT-DO",    "T-5",  "T-5",  "XCP-8",    "A-1",  "CCS-6",    "T-2",  "EES-17",   "EES-17",   "P-1",  "M-3",  "T-4",  "MPA-MAGLAB",   "CCS-6",    "C-IIAC",   "XCP-3",    "SIGMA-1",  "T-2",  "T-1",  "MST-8",    "MST-8",    "CCS-2",    "ISR-6",    "MPA-Q",    "MPA-Q",    "T-3",  "P-4",  "E-6",  "XTD-PRI",  "M-6"), 
                          Cols = c("#66666660", "#66666660",    "#F0027F",  "#F0027F",  "#BEAED4",  "#7FC97F",  "#7FC97F",  "#7FC97F",  "#7FC97F",  "#7FC97F",  "#386CB0",  "#386CB0",  "#F0027F",  "#F0027F",  "#FDC086",  "#FDC086",  "#386CB0",  "#386CB0",  "#66666660",    "#66666660",    "#66666660",    "#FDC086",  "#7FC97F",  "#BEAED4",  "#66666660",    "#66666660",    "#66666660",    "#66666660",    "#BEAED4",  "#F0027F",  "#F0027F",  "#66666660",    "#66666660"))
```

**Graphing the network**

```
library(igraph)
stack_graph <- graph_from_data_frame(stack.edges, vertices = stack.vtx, directed = TRUE)

plot(stack_graph, 
     layout = layout_in_circle(stack_graph), 
     vertex.color = V(stack_graph)$Cols,
     vertex.shape = "sphere",
     vertex.label.color = "black",
     vertex.size = V(stack_graph)$Count * 4,
     vertex.label = "",
     edge.size = 0.3, 
     edge.color = E(stack_graph)$Cols, 
     edge.curved = 0.2, 
     edge.arrow.size = 0) #Changing this flag with anything > 0 will cause transparency issues of the graph vertices
```

The resulting graph with `directed = TRUE` OR `edge.arrow.size = 0.1` (or anything greater than zero, will produce a graph with the vertex colors that are transparent. Here is what it looks like:

[image: Transparent Vertices]

However, the resulting graph when `directed = FALSE` OR `edge.arrow.size = 0` will produce a graph with the vertex colors that are 'normal' or what is desired from this code. Here is what it looks like:

[image: Non Transparent Vertices]

The closest solution I have found can be found in this post: [Unexpected arrow color behavior with semi-transparent edges (igraph, R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37028723/unexpected-arrow-color-behavior-with-semi-transparent-edges-igraph-r).

it is suggested to make the vertices smaller (ex. `vertex.size`. However, reducing the vertex.size still keeps the transparent vertices (when `directed = TRUE`. Additionally, passing the `edge.arrow.mode` suggested in the post, has no effect.

Any suggestions as to how I can obtain non-transparent vertices when `graph_from_data_frame(directed = TRUE)`?

Comment: Does it help to set the vertex colours directly from the vertex dataframe like: `plot(stack_graph, ..., vertex.color = stack.vtx$Cols)`?

Comment: I'm curious: what OS? What IDE are you using? What package versions do you have? If not Windows, what graphic device are you using? No matter what I do to this plot the nodes are opaque. I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I did try passing the `vertex.color = stack.vtx$Cols` and I still get the transparent vertices when `directed = TRUE`. 

My `sessionInfo()` output = R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23) 
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Monterey 12.6.2 (the latest one) 

Attached packages: igraph_1.3.5. I am using RStudio version 2022.12.0+353 (the latest one). The graphics I am using = AMD Radeon Pro 5500M 8 GB. 

To note - I can run other `igraph` plots with edge and vertex colors w/out issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change #66666660 into for example #666666. That is drop the alpha channel RRGGBB60 in #RRGGBBAA.

This problem is also reproducible on Windows, Rgui.

**Small example**

```
library(igraph)
stack_graph <- make_ring(2, directed=TRUE)

plot(stack_graph, 
     layout = layout_in_circle(stack_graph), 
     vertex.shape = "sphere",
     edge.color = c("#66666660"),   # Transparency issues are caused by non valid RBG color code.
     edge.arrow.size = 2            # Changing this flag with anything > 0 will show transparency issues of the graph vertices.
     )
```

**Edit:** If `edge.color = rgb(red=0x66/255, green=0x66/255, blue=0x66/255, alpha=0.3)` in plot() is set as transparent, then the vertices will also be rendered transparent after saving in the .pdf file. Most likely an igraph bug.

Comment: Thank-you. This actually worked. To note, the #66666660 is #666666 but with transparency 60, so #66666660 - I've used this quite a bit in plotting graphs (and learned how to do this on this website a while back). However, it seems as if igraph makes everything transparent, even if one color is coded with a transparency. Again, thank-you for pointing this out.